# How do I use `@transaction` to rollback the registered user in case Email fails to generate?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, dj-rest-auth

I am building a simple `django-rest-framework` backend that uses `dj-rest-auth` authentication system with the following settings

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
```

I want to ensure that in case of failure in email-generation the registered user is rolled back.

This is my `serializer.py`

```
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self, request):
        try:
            user = super().save(request)
            user.first_name = self.data.get('first_name')
            user.last_name = self.data.get('last_name')
            user.save()
            return user
        except <...What exception has to be caught?...>:
            transaction.set_rollback(True)
            return
```

What exception do i have to catch and am I doing this right? How do I achieve this?

For reference, this is the error generated in case of wrong values in `settings.py` file

```
Exception Type: ConnectionRefusedError at /api/auth/register/
Exception Value: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Also is it possible to rollback in case of user submitting a wrong email and email fails to deliver?

Comment: Concentrate and read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly)

Answer (score 0):

`@transaction.atomic` will execute a transaction on the database if your view produces a **response without errors**. Because you're catching the exception yourself, it appears to Django that your view executed just fine.

If you catch the exception, you need to handle it yourself. Raise an exception or return an error.

About your second question, you can validate the email before sending email, also any email sending related error will raise an error.